# Run bash_profile in cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I had a problem that my cron script wasnt loading the environment variables so I added the following line:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash /root/.bash_profile
```

This seems to have no effect and the path variables are not being set correctly.
How do I run the bash_profile script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash /root/.bash_profile` will create a new `bash` process, run that file (and I assume set your env variables while doing so), and then exit, taking those newly set env variables with it.

Try `. /root/.bash_profile`.  Or `source /root/.bash_profile`.  That will execute the file in the current bash process, so your env variables will be available to the current process.

You may also want to use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` if you're going to do bash-style invocations.

Answer (score 1):

`. /root/.bash_profile` or `source /root/.bash_profile`.  which says to run that file in the current shell.  Your method runs `.bash_profile` in s subshell,  That sets up the variables in the subshell, then this subshell exits, taking these variables with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the variables in the `.bash_profile` file, you need to source it in your script.

Simply executing the script will not include the exported variables.